# JS/html запрет, отключение форм, действий

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, подскажите какой самый эффективный способ, запретить использование элементов. Допустим есть блок с формой, textarea, кнопкой, инпутами, и так далее, так вот, при определенном условии, мне нужно просто disable, все что находится в определенном радиусе, чтобы это можно было только видеть. Я думал про невидимый блок, который можно наложить сверху, затем при определенных условиях убрать, но не уверен что это best way решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так.

Скрипт находит все элементы форм внутри формы и добавляет (убирает) `disabled`.

```js
function ToggleEnable() {
   var form = document.getElementById("form1");
   var ells = form.querySelectorAll("input,textarea");
   for(var el of ells) {
     if(el.getAttribute("disabled") == "disable") {
       el.removeAttribute("disabled");
     } else {
       el.setAttribute("disabled","disable");
     }
   }
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
 <p><input type="text" value="xxxxxx"> </p>
 <p><input type="password" value="111111"> </p>
 <p><textarea>11111111
2222222222222</textarea> </p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" ></p>
</form>

<a href="javascript://" onclick="ToggleEnable()">disable/enable</a>
```

Comment: логичнее дизейблить форму же. И да, селектор у вас выберет все textarea на странице.

Comment: @MedvedevDev форма как я понимаю не дизейблится. На счёт `textarea` спасибо, запятая работала не так как я ожидал ))

Comment: я имел ввиду, что логичнее прерывать event submit у формы.

Comment: @MedvedevDev но данные можно будет ввести в этом случае, кроме того стиль не поменяется

Comment: @MedvedevDev но ваше решение тоже думаю подходит совестно с наложение div поверх, например, но это уже не относится к моему ответу, это другое решение

Comment: Не, скорее нужен класс форме (для стилей) и прерывание сабмита. Блок поверх это очень костыльно звучит.

Comment: @MedvedevDev так стиль вам не запретит вводить данные в инпуты, хотя может это и можно стилем задать, я не знаю как

Comment: А в чем смысл? Отправленные данные формируются сразу, то что там наменяют в процессе отправки - это дело десятое. Хотя тут конечно зависит от задачи, может вы и правы.